# Finding an update related to the user's products in Prisma

Tags: javascript, database, prisma

I have a schema where a user has multiple products and products have multiple updates. Updates table has no foreign key for user but for product. I want to find an update with Id but I also want to make sure the update is scoped to current logged in user.

```
model User {
  id        String    @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  username  String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  password  String    @db.VarChar(255)
  products  Product[]
}
model Product {
  id          String   @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(255)
  belongsToId String   @db.Uuid
  belongsTo   User     @relation(fields: [belongsToId], references: [id])
  updates     Update[]
  @@unique([id, belongsToId])
}
model Update {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime

  title  String        @db.VarChar(255)
  body   String
  status UPDATE_STATUS @default(IN_PROGRESS)

  version String?
  asset   String?

  productId    String        @db.Uuid
  product      Product       @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  updatePoints UpdatePoint[]
}
```

I have tried to find a single product with `findFirst` but I don't even get to the product which contains the update. I tried `findMany` and that sends back all products with the one I need.

```js
  const product = await prisma.product.findMany({
    where: { belongsToId: req.user.id },
    include: {
      updates: {
        where: { id: req.params.id },
      },
    },
  });
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "bdd8d760-de94-4693-abab-b4685b52ac93",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-12T18:04:09.517Z",
      "name": "Note Stuff app",
      "belongsToId": "5754b464-9446-44de-9135-0beb6cac83f8",
      "updates": []
    },
    {
      "id": "f9a7b8cf-b0fc-443f-a9fc-b1ea8ff42799",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-13T05:23:20.497Z",
      "name": "Sledge Hammer",
      "belongsToId": "5754b464-9446-44de-9135-0beb6cac83f8",
      "updates": [
        {
          "id": "4f781638-0d39-4e65-816d-0fd816721c26",
          "createdAt": "2022-11-13T05:25:21.614Z",
          "updatedAt": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "title": "Adding metal",
          "body": "Sledge hammer is now more heavy",
          "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
          "version": null,
          "asset": null,
          "productId": "f9a7b8cf-b0fc-443f-a9fc-b1ea8ff42799"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The first product `Note Stuff app` should not be there because the update I searched is in second product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, I can use children array in where clause.

```js
  const product = await prisma.product.findFirst({
    where: {
      belongsToId: req.user.id,
      updates: { some: { id: req.params.id } },
    },
    include: {
      updates: {
        where: { id: req.params.id },
      },
    },
  });
```

I'm using `some` key on `updates` key in `where` key. Allowing me to put where clause on children.